# How to exclude .DS_Store when creating rar file on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, rar

According to the manpage of rar

```
rar a -r -x.DS_Store "rar file name" "folder"
```

should exclude .DS_Store from being packed into rar file. But it does not work.

I also tried:

```
rar a -r -x".DS_Store" "rar file name" "folder"
rar a -r -x"*/.DS_Store" "rar file name" "folder"
rar a -r -x"*.DS_Store" "rar file name" "folder"
```

None of them works.

Comment: Which rar are you running? Which version of macOS? At least on my machine there is no rar bundled with macos.

Comment: @DerMolly Sorry I forgot mention that. I installed rar through Homebrew, version now is RAR 6.12, macOS version: 12.4 (21F79).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it.

```
rar a -r -x'*/.DS_Store' "rar file name" "folder"
```

will do the trick.